# momentJS Timer doesn´t work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, setinterval, momentjs

I implemented a countdown timer via Moment.js library, and unfortunately it doesn't work on Firefox.
This is my code:

```
function createTimer(begin, timeUp) {
    var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    var timerDays = document.getElementById('days').children[0];
    var timerHours = document.getElementById('hours').children[0];
    var timerMinutes = document.getElementById('minutes').children[0];
    var timerSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds').children[0];

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
        // Difference between timeUp and now
        var differenceToTimeUp = moment.duration(timeUp.diff(moment()));
        // Difference between begin and now
        var differenceToBegin = moment.duration(begin.diff(moment()));
        if (differenceToTimeUp.asSeconds() > 0) {
            timer.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            timer.classList.add('hidden');
        }
        timerDays.innerText = ('0' + differenceToTimeUp.days()).slice(-2);
        timerHours.innerText = ('0' + differenceToTimeUp.hours()).slice(-2);
        timerMinutes.innerText = ('0' + differenceToTimeUp.minutes()).slice(-2);
        timerSeconds.innerText = ('0' + differenceToTimeUp.seconds()).slice(-2);
    }, 1000);

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

//        // Comment out for production
//        var test1 = moment('2016-02-02 11:00:00');
//        var test2 = moment('2016-03-11 11:00:00');
//        createTimer(test1, test2);

    var now =  moment(new Date(moment())).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    
    var firstStart = moment('2016-02-11 11:00:00');
    var firstEnd = moment('2016-02-15 17:00:00');
   
    var secondStart = moment('2016-02-16 14:00:00');
    var secondEnd = moment('2016-02-17 17:00:00');
    
    if (now > firstStart._i && now < firstEnd._i) {
        createTimer(firstStart, firstEnd);
    }

});
```

In debugger I can see that moment is getting the date, so I think it has something to do with the `setInterval` function.
Any ideas?

#### UPDATE

Got it working. The mistake was actually not with momentJS. Changing the Text element with .innerText didn´t work on InternetExplorer. Using .textContent fixed it. I hade issues with my custom fonts as well on InternetExplorer when i used .tff. Using .woff worked fine.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods in moment.js?

Comment: is console throwing any error or warning?

Comment: @SlashmanX good point, i didn´t know there was this option. As soon as i fix this issue i will try it out. Thanks

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude unfortunately there is no error thrown...

Comment: It's weird, I use moment.js with firefox without problems, and the only possible mistake that I see in your code is the use of a reserved word (`begin`). This is possible make crash? I don't know, but you can try.

Comment: Okay i will try it. The weird thing is that it comes to the line where i overwrite timerDays.innerText etc. where it shows me the value in the debugger which is changing. But it won´t be displayed in the browser?! So moment and setINterval is working. But displaying on browser wont work

Comment: i changed begin to start (maybe bad idea?) but still won´t fix. The values won´t be displayed at the browser, but like i said obviously the will be changed in the "something.innerText"